# Next.js Lifting state up

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-props, react-state-management

`_app.js`

```js
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>      
            <Layout>
                <Component {...pageProps} />
            </Layout>
    );
}

export default MyApp;
```

`Layout.js`

```js
function Layout({ children }) {
    const [cartOpen, setCartOpen] = useState(false);
    const handleOpen = () => setCartOpen(!cartOpen);

    return (
        <>
            <Cart cartOpen={cartOpen} handleOpen={handleOpen} />
            <main>{children}</main>
        </>  
    )
}
```

`ProductPage.js`

```js
function ProductPage(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => console.log('set state to true in cartOpen(defined in layout.js)')}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Inside the `ProductPage` component which is the child component of `Layout`, I want an element to have a `OnClick` Event handler which will change state in Layout component to `setCartOpen(true)`

[Link to sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-leaf-1q0e6?file=/pages/index.js)

Comment: pass `setCartOpen` or a function as prop to ProductPage and call that function in ProductPage

Comment: Or you can use React Context to make the callback available in `ProductPage`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can leverage React Context to make `setCartOpen` available to any components down the tree.

```js
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';

export const CartContext = createContext(null);

function Layout({ children }) {
    const [cartOpen, setCartOpen] = useState(false);
    const handleOpen = () => setCartOpen(!cartOpen);

    return (
        <CartContext.Provider value={{ cartOpen, setCartOpen }}>
            <Cart cartOpen={cartOpen} handleOpen={handleOpen} />
            <main>{children}</main>
        </CartContext.Provider>  
    )
}

export default Layout;
```

Then, in your page, just retrieve `setCartOpen` from context and use it.

```js
import { CartContext } from '<your-path-to>/Layout';

function ProductPage(props) {
    const { setCartOpen } = useContext(CartContext);

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => setCartOpen(true)}>Open Cart</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default ProductPage;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i solved the query using a similar approach.i moved the state managed by react to redux which is same idea of sharing state across components as mentioned in your answer

Comment: Thanks, very helpfull I wanted to the button to display {cartOpen} how would I change the code?

Comment: @JohnMayer You'd need to also pass `cartOpen` in the context provider: `<CartContext.Provider value={{ cartOpen, setCartOpen }}>`. You could then access it through context in the `ProductPage` component: `const { cartOpen, setCartOpen } = useContext(CartContext);`.

Comment: Thanks! That worked well!